# Extract text from image containing a table

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image which contains a table in it. I need to extract the text from it. I tried to remove horizontal and vertical lines first, but it doesn't seems to work. Below is the code which I used.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'A13205.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4, 4))
morph_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

#inverse the image, so that lines are black for masking
morph_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(morph_img)

#perform bitwise_and to mask the lines with provided mask
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_xor(thresh, thresh, mask = morph_img)
```

[Input from which text must be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVBjt.png)

Comment: Try first samples from OpenCV: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text/samples